# how to modify a specfic object at index in core data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Sorry if this question is very simple, but i am new to coredata world. I have current project and someone is already implanted coredata in it. I like to know how to modify a specific object at specific index in core data ? What are the steps i need to follow.

Thank you your help and sorry for stupid question.

Comment: What do you mean by a specific index? Like in the results of a fetch request?

Comment: If you are very new to core data you should probably look up the apple documentation on this before you start working on it. A quick read would answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its simplest form it looks something like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:￼@"Entity"];
fetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attribute = %@"￼, value￼];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch 
                           error:nil];
NSManagedObject *obj = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

This will only work if there is at least one result of the fetch. You have to do the usual error checking, etc.

I concur with the others that you should read up using the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).